# Find if a package is installed

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, package-management

Ubuntu 9.10

I am wondering what apt-cache show emacs.

However, it gives information about emacs but doesn't show if it is currently installed or not.

How can I find if a package and version is currently installed?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dpkg:

```
dpkg -s emacs
```

there is also `dpkg-query` which allows you to use wildcards in your search:

```
dpkg-query -l '*emacs*'
```

Comment: I did try aptitude show emacs. This is a snippet: "State: not installed"

Comment: didn't know about `dpkg-query`; i've always just used `dpkg -l | grep emacs` or similar.