# Test if a package is installed in APT

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, package-management, apt

I want a shell script method to test/report if a package is installed. I don't need details, only boolean return to set logic flow. I looked at [Find if a package is installed](https://superuser.com/questions/80764/find-if-a-package-is-installed), but `dpkg` returns complex output and its format changes depending on whether the package is in the Debian repository or in an Ubuntu PPA.

I found that `apt-cache` does a pretty good job and I came up with this method:

```
is_installed=0
test_installed=( `apt-cache policy package-name | grep "Installed:" ` )
[ ! "${test_installed[1]}" == "(none)" ] && is_installed=1
```

Does anyone know a simpler or more direct way?

Answer (score 12):

`dpkg-query` as in your linked post seems to be the most correct tool for the job, except using e.g. the available Python libraries to bind directly to the APT system in such a scripting context.

With `dpkg-query`:

```bash
dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' package-name 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^i'
```

Will return true (exit status `0` in shell script) if the package is installed, false (exit status `1`) otherwise.

- `-W` means "Show" (`dpkg-query` must have a requested action).
- `-f` changes the format of the output.
- `db:Status-abbrev` is the short form of the package status.
- `2>/dev/null` silences `dpkg-query` if an invalid package name is given. How this should be handled could be a case-to-case issue.
- `grep -q` returns true if there is a match, false otherwise.

If it is used often, it could be made a simple function:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
debInst() {
    dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^i'
}

if debInst "$1"; then
    printf 'Why yes, the package %s _is_ installed!\n' "$1"
else
    printf 'I regret to inform you that the package %s is not currently installed.\n' "$1"
fi
```

or just simply

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^i'; then
    printf 'Why yes, the package "%s" _is_ installed!\n' "$1"
else
    printf 'I regret to inform you that the package "%s" is not currently installed.\n' "$1"
fi
```

Comment: While this is doubtless correct I find that `dpkg-query -l "$package" | grep -q ^.i` is usually sufficient (and easier to remember).

Comment: @phogg: Yes, depends on whether it is supposed to live in a script or not. Also, the `dpkg-query -l` output is not set in stone since it is just a user presentation mode, so if the presentation changes perhaps such a script would break.

Comment: @Daniel. I like the return code approach. Please see my answer with details in code.

Comment: On 10.04 the format option db:Status-abbrev doesn't seem to exist -- I used: `dpkg-query -Wf'${Version}' ${pkg} 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^\d*'` to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I like Daniel Andersson's answer, but it didn't work for me.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

From the [dpkg man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg-query.1.html), `db:Status-abbrev` only works in dpkg 1.16.2+:

```
          db:Status-Abbrev
                 It  contains the abbreviated package status, such as “ii”
                 (since dpkg 1.16.2).
```

My solution was to use legacy behavior, just the `Status` formatter:

```
dpkg-query -Wf'${Status}' {my_pkg_name}
```

outputs

```
install ok installed
```

I'm guessing this was the inspiration for "ii" in other representations.

So, to completely adapt Daniel Andersson's answer to work on older version of dpkg, and thus older Ubuntu distros:

```
dpkg-query -Wf'${Status}' {your_pkg_name} 2>/dev/null | grep -q "install ok installed"
```

Returns:

- 0 - package is installed, or
- 1 - package is NOT installed.

Answer (score 1):

I tested Daniel's suggestions on three packages with these results:

1. Native Debian repository package not installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' apache-perl
   ~$ echo $?
   1
   ```
2. PPA package registered on host and installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' libreoffice
   ~$ echo $?
   0
   ```
3. PPA package registered on host but not installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-abbrev}' domy-ce
   ~$ echo $?
   0
   ~$ sudo apt-get remove domy-ce
   [sudo] password for user: 
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Package domy-ce is not installed, so not removed
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```

Although I like the approach, it seems I can't trust the return code with PPA packages. Short of that, I think I'll stick with parsing the return of the `apt-cache policy` command.

Comment: Well, your code examples are not what I said you should do, but I guess you have just missed the `grep` part in your pasting. I can't really reproduce your issue, but that might be because the code examples are currently incomplete, so please fix that. Do you run Debian or Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 (are PPA's supported no straight Debian?). My code dropped the your grep because 1) the dkpg-query command writes nothing to stdout and grep always throws a returncode. The dpkg-query returncode is 0 if installed.

Comment: 1. Don't tag your post "Debian" then. 2. I don't think you understood the part `grep` played in the command, so you stripped it, and now you say it doesn't work? `grep -q` gives return code `1` if it **doesn't** match, i.e. the program is __not__ installed or unavailable, or `0` if the program is installed. I explained that in my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for dependencies 
check_deps () {
DEPS=$(echo {dialog,sqlite3,openssh-client})
for i in $DEPS ; do
    dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' | grep ^$i$ > /dev/null
    if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        echo "Installing deps ..."
        aptitude install $i -y > /dev/null
    fi
done  
}

# execute the check_deps function
check_deps
```

Comment: -1, the question is not about dependency checking. Also, explain what the parts of the command is doing: otherwise other people can't see what's going on.

Comment: `DEPS=$(echo {dialog,sqlite3,openssh-client})` can be equivalently written as just `DEPS="dialog sqlite3 openssh-client"`.